# NXDOMAIN when switching from A records to CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system

For our site, we recently tried changing our DNS records from using A records to using a CNAME.

When we changed the records and waited 24 hours we got an NXDOMAIN error.  At that point we reverted to the previous records and the site came back almost instantly.

I have read that it may take up to 48 hours for new records to propagate, but from what I understand that is because it just keeps using older cached records.  Both the old and new set of records should work, so why am I getting an NXDOMAIN error?  Or, to be more specific: how was a negative cache ever created?  It either should've still had the old records in cache, or it should've asked our DNS server for the new ones, right?

While I was getting the NXDOMAIN error, I used [DNS Checker](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php) to see what records were being used.  It said that there were no records at all.  Neither A records nor CNAME.  I suppose that makes sense given the NXDOMAIN error, but figured I'd mention it anyway as further evidence.

I feel that there must be something here that I'm not understanding.  How was a negative cache ever created when there always should've been a valid set of records in our DNS server?

Comment: CNAME records require A records. CNAME records are not replacements for A records and cannot be used in lieu of A records. https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/cname-record/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.  I'm saying I have a CNAME on subdomain.example.com that points to example.com.  What it leads to has A records, but the subdomain doesn't.

Comment: "I'm afraid I don't understand." Give the real data (name involved) instead of obfuscation. That would help people troubleshooting things and give you better replies.

Answer (score 1):

A good tip is to lower the TTL values of your records to 300 seconds before implementing changes, and then waiting for your old TTL value (usually 24 hours) before doing any changes. That way any cached response of the old records with the old value will have time to expire, and any changes you make will propagate within 5 minutes instead of 24 hours. After you've verified that everything works as intended, you can set the TTL value back to 24 hours to lower the load on your DNS infrastructure.

Comment: Technically, depending on the setup, you would also potentially need to lower the Refresh timer as well eventually the Negative TTL one. Also obviously when you change the TTL on a record you have to wait for a time at least of the **old** TTL before doing anything else.